# how to append arbitrary string to yasnippet placeholder field

Tags: yasnippet

I would like to know how to append a default string to a placeholder.

For example, I currently have:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: render template
# key: rt
# group: Flask
# contributor: Jon Rostran
# --
render_template("${0:index.html}")
```

But I would like for `rt` to expand to `render_template("|.html")` where the `|` is my cursor position after expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Was making things harder than I thought. Solved it with this `render_template("$0.html")`

EDIT:

### Explanation

The default expansion of `render_template("${0:index.html}")` is `render_template("index.html")`, but I would like to save myself from overriding `"index.html"` and manage typing the `.html` extension by default. Thus, `render_template("$0.html")` allows me to type only the name of the file so that after expansion I start typing here `render_template("|.html")`, without overriding and typing `.html` part again.

Comment: Please elaborate - explain how that solves the problem (answers the question).

Comment: The default expansion of `render_template("${0:index.html}")` is `render_template("index.html")`, but I would like to save myself from overriding `index.html` and manage typing the `.html` extension by default. Thus, `render_template("$0.html")` allows me to type only the name of the file so after expansion I start typing here `render_template("|.html")`, without overriding and typing `.html` again.

Comment: Put all such explanation into the question or answer. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.